# How to provide a detail reason if shipping address is invalid in Apple Pay

Tags: ios, applepay

Currently, we only show a red exclamation mark next to the shipping address if it is invalid.

[image: Apple Pay invalid address]

*Image from http://tech.mercari.com/entry/2016/05/19/150000*

But how do we provide a detail reason to our customer about why the shipping address is invalid?

For example:

- The product is not able to ship to PO BOX.
- We only ship to 48 contiguous states.
- ...

```c
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                  didSelectShippingAddress:(ABRecordRef)address
                                completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus status, NSArray *shippingMethods, NSArray *summaryItems))completion {
    if ([self isPoBox:address]) {
        completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusInvalidShippingPostalAddress, nil, nil);
    }];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible in Apple Pay. It certainly is not possible in Apple Pay JS. I imagine this is a design decision on Apple's part so that they can "own" as much of the native Apple Pay sheet as possible.

Comment: Make sure to open an enhancement request with Apple about this at https://bugreport.apple.com and post the number here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both *Apple Pay* and *Apple Pay for the Web*, you only get part of the shipping address when you're on the Paysheet as you've shown.

The parts you get are

- City `locality`
- State `adminstrativeArea`
- Zip `postalCode`
- Country `country` and `countryCode`

They do NOT give you the **name** or **street address** until after the payment has been authorized by the TouchID.

This does cause a problem with PO Boxes, since you don't know it's a PO Box until after the user has authorized the purchase. As another comment pointed out, Apple owns the Paysheet and you really can't do much about it at this point.

You basically have two options when it comes to PO Boxes.

- After the payment has been authorized, you can still stop the order. It's not going to charge the card until you submit the `paymentToken` to your credit card processor. You can simply message to the customer that **Sorry, we cannot ship to PO Boxes** and get them to click the Apple Pay button again and use a different address.
- Contact the customer afterward and get a different shipping address (yuck)